# FormData with Ajax upload file cross domain ,how can the server get the file?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, file-upload, web

my domain is localhost:8084,want to upload file to localhost:8086
the js is

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("post", "http://localshot:8086"+ "?type=ajax",true);   
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");  
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data;");  
    // 模拟数据  
    var fd = new FormData();  
    fd.append("upfile", f);  //f is a File object
    fd.append("result","tskdskfjsf");  
    xhr.send(fd);  
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
                                    var r = e.target.response, json;
                                    me.uploadComplete(r);
                                    if (i == fileList.length - 1) {
                                        $(img).remove()
                                    }
                                });
```

the server(java) :

```
    System.out.print(getPara("result"));  
    UploadFile uf = getFile("upfile", path.getAbsolutePath() + "/");
```

my question :

1. i will get no data in console.
2. when executed the statement`getFile("upfile",path.getAbsolutePath() + "/")` will throw    an exception `"java.io.IOException: Posted content type isn't multipart/form-data"`

the method getFile is from third framework:

```
public UploadFile getFile(String parameterName, String saveDirectory) {
    getFiles(saveDirectory);
    return getFile(parameterName);
}  

public List<UploadFile> getFiles(String saveDirectory) {
    if (multipartRequest == null) {
        multipartRequest = new MultipartRequest(request, saveDirectory);
        request = multipartRequest;
    }
    return multipartRequest.getFiles();
}
```

expect your help ,thanks!

Comment: How is implemented `getFile` ?

Comment: @dystroy  i edit my question ,expect to make the question clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well use Apache File Upload Utils library to make it more easy. For cross domain policy, you have to solve it some server side policies, or use some proxy server like nginx.

Comment: getResponse().addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8084");   
   getResponse().addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", " POST, GET, OPTIONS");  
    getResponse().addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");  i have already get the CROS

Comment: if you already have the CORS, enable it and try. This could be case of invalid request format only.

Comment: I'm not sure this will enable CORS in your container. The browser will check with OPTIONS request in case of a cross domain call, and in that case do you think these headers will be reaching your client?

Comment: ,thanks ,  but ,as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) said `"It uses the same format a form would use if the encoding type were set to "multipart/form-data"."`,how could this happen

Comment: well thats correct. and the CORS is only for the client not for the server. I think the AJAX request you make is having some problems. Chcek with APache libraries and verify the requests are proper

Comment: ,i'm sorry ,i can't get it,what i did is make a breakpoint ,and the exception is not about the same source policy,maybe it means ,cross domain is sucess ,but get no data at server

Comment: ,really appreiciate,i solved the problem ,as i add the custom header in xmlhttpreques object ,so it made the preflight,but at server i have not get the response header  getResponse().addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");  when i add this in reponse,everyting is ok,and  i think never add a custom header is better!